# Trivial Perfect Code

Tags: coding-theory

I want to know how to apply definition of perfect code to  this code ( I want to prove $C$ is perfect :-

The binary codes $C$ of odd length consisting of a vector $ \bf{c} $ and the complementary vector $\bar{\bf{c}} $  with $0$s and $1$s interchanged .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** For any binary word $w$ of length $2n+1$, (where $2n+1$ is your odd number) you can prove that

$$d(w,c)+d(w,\bar{c})= 2n+1 \,.$$

This is easy because every binary digit in $w$ is either the same as the digit in $c$ and opposite than the digit in $\bar{C}$, or the other way around.

Now, all you need is show that if two non-negative integers add to $2n+1$, one has to be $\leq n$ and the other has to be $\geq n+1$.

Comment: The result should also follow using the sphere packing bound.

Comment: what of I understand in your asnwer is  $ C$ will be the enter the vector space  $ F^{2n+1}_2$.