# The Three Trivial Perfect Codes

Tags: coding-theory

On Coding Theory, there's three trivial perfect codes.

They are:

- Binary codes of odd length
- Codes with contains only one codeword
- Codes that are the whole $A^n_q$

So, the $A^n_q$ case, considering the definition that says "A perfect code is a code such $A_q^n$ is the disjoint union of balls of some fixed radius centered on the codewords" is trivial by taking the radius to be 0.

But the other two cases I can't see why. Any hints to demonstrate that?
(Could it be that codes with one codeword are analogue to the $A_q^n$ case? Taking the radius to be n or M=|C|)

Comment: For the second case, yes, just take your radius to be suitably large, and you're done. For the first, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503773/trivial-perfect-code?rq=1) should help.

Comment: Oh, I see it now! Thanks!